# Eclipse code assist and closure compiler annotations

Tags: eclipse, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

Sorry for removing the original question but will try to save you from having to read through a lot of things I've tried that don't work very well.

Basically Eclipse with JSDT can't do the job. Tried to define all my namespaces with constructor functions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103951/bad-type-annotation-unknown-type) (end of the question last update). But it's all too much trouble.

Trying netbeans now and it'll assist most of the closure library and all of my code. Some things like goog.array won't complete because goog.array is never defined. When adding `goog.array=new Object()` to the array.js it'll complete goog.array and goog.array.ArrayLike. These modded js file go in your js/libs directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be used as a type, `DOM` must be annotated as a constructor or interface.

```
/** @constructor Interaction between dom and js code */
function DOM(){}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question about warnings I was getting trying to solve this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103951/bad-type-annotation-unknown-type). If this is the "right way" and this works I'll update this question.

Answer (score 1):

**tern.java** provides a [support for Google Closure Library](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Closure-support) inside Eclipse. It integrates the tern plugin [tern-closure](https://github.com/google/tern-closure) which is very powerful: it uses JS sources of Google Closure and manages closure compiler annotations.